# Parsing huge XML file using Go

Tags: xml, go, sax

We need to parse a huge XML file using Go. We'd like to use a SAX-like event based algorithm using `xml.NewDecoder()` and `decoder.Token()` library calls. We've created the appropriate struct types with XML annotations. Everything easy peasy so far.

Now, we go through the file and detect the `xml.StartElement` tokens. And here comes the problem. We need to decode ONLY the attributes of this starting token and continue into its content. If we call `token.DecodeElement()` the whole content is "decoded" or skipped in our scenario.

How to decode only the attributes of a specific `StartElement` and continue to the element's body?

Comment: You don't need `token.DecodeElement()` at all. Just continue with the `for { token, _ := dec.Token();  switch x := token.(type) { ...} } ` loop.

Comment: But how to parse the attributes? We don't want something like `x := token.Attr[3].Value`...

Comment: Why not? This is what I do: `for _, v := range x.Attr {...}` and it works well enough for me.

Comment: @topskip OK, I wondered if there isn't some "magic" and more idiomatic solution. But why not that, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I parse wikipedia xml dumps (~50GB xml files) in [go-wikiparse](https://github.com/dustin/go-wikiparse) using plain struct/reflect decoding.  It's super simple.

The strategy is basically this:

First, read the envelope token:

```
d := xml.NewDecoder(r)
_, err := d.Token()
if err != nil {
    return nil, err
}
```

e.g., for `<someDocument><billions-of-other-things/></someDocument>` that will give you someDocument.

Then, you can just struct decode the next things in a loop:

```
var i item
d.Decode(&i)
```

Not much RAM, and it's super easy to parse.

Comment: Perfect, Dustin, I completely overlooked `Decode()`.